# Explicit in selenium

Tags: selenium, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to get div value, but the fallowing code is not waiting for the page, just for URL. I used `time.sleep`, which is very primitive and totally not flexible. I want to change it on the explicit, but I am not too experienced in Python and I have a problem with that.

The website name has been changed just in case :

```
def repeat():
    import wx
    while True:
        botloc = driver.find_element_by_id('botloc').text
        print botloc
        botX,botY = map(int,botloc.split(','))
        print botX
        print botY
        wx.Yield()
def checker():
    if driver.current_url == 'logged.example.com':
        time.sleep(5)
        repeat()
    else:
        checker()
checker()
```

How can I replace `time.sleep` with something flexible to wait the shortest time as possible after the page will be loaded? How to use explicit correctly with my code?

I know that's possible with using an element from the website, but I can't write anything sensible, I just need an example.

Is possibility to use `element_by_id('botloc')` for wait till it will be visible then start repeat() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i replace time.sleep with something flexible to wait shortest
>   time as possible after the page will be loaded?

I suppose you use `get(url)` to load the page. Generally you don't have to do anything, WebDriver automatically waits until page is being loaded. So you can remove `time.sleep()`. However there are some issues reported when loading the page using `get` with firefox driver, because of that you will have to wait for some target element which is supposed to be in the loaded page as mentioned below.

> How to use explicit correctly with my code?

Have you checked Selenium webdriver documentation ? you can wait for `botloc` element explicitly as below

```
//assuming you have a valid webdriver reference
//Ex: DEFAULT_WAIT = 10 means
//waits up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException or if it finds the element will return it in 0 - 10 seconds.

element = WebDriverWait(webdriver, DEFAULT_WAIT).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "botloc")))
```

Refer this [page](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) for more information

Comment: **You don't have to do anything, WebDriver automatically waits until page is being loaded. So you can remove time.sleep()** From my experience `driver.current_url` is not waiting until page is being loaded, is waiting unit current url adress will be visible.

Comment: Which driver are you using ? hmm.. saw some page loading issues in Firefox driver.